# WPF MVVM DevExpress Memoedit and Combobox control not opening Popup when placed in GridControl

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, devexpress-wpf

The GridControl in my view has a Memoedit control and a combobox control. Following is my XAML code for DataGrid:

```
<dxg:GridControl x:Name="gridFloorplans" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" AutoGenerateColumns="None" 
            ItemsSource="{Binding FloorplanList.Result.View}"
            SelectedItems="{Binding Path=SelectedFloorplan,Mode=TwoWay}"
            dx:ThemeManager.Theme="Default" SelectionMode="Row">
            <dxg:GridControl.View>
                <dxg:TableView AllowGrouping="False" ShowGroupPanel="False" AllowEditing="False"  ShowDataNavigator="True" DataNavigatorButtons="Navigation" />
            </dxg:GridControl.View>
            <dxg:GridControl.Columns>
                <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="Id" />
                <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="Name" Header="Floorplan Name" Fixed="Left" />
                <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="Season"  Fixed="Left" />
                <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="Version"  Fixed="Left" />
                <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="IssueDate" />
                <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="LiveDate"  />
                <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="ExpirationDate" />
                <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="Notes" Header="Notes" >
                <!-- Need to fill this in with a text popup icon -->
                    <dxg:GridColumn.EditSettings>
                        <dxe:MemoEditSettings/>
                    </dxg:GridColumn.EditSettings>
                </dxg:GridColumn>
                <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="Status">
                <dxg:GridColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                    <dxe:ComboBoxEdit ItemsSource="{Binding SourceStatusList}">                            
                        </dxe:ComboBoxEdit>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </dxg:GridColumn.CellTemplate>                    
                </dxg:GridColumn>
                <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="FloorplanSpecialist" />
                <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="LayoutFileName" />
                <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="IsVirtualStore" Header="Virtual Store" />
                <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="IsRemodelStore" Header="Project" />
                <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="Zone" Header="FP Zone" />
                <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="ILCStatus" />
                <!--<dxg:GridColumn FieldName="IsFloorplanIdStore" Header="FP Id Store" />-->
                <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="MerchAreaKey" />
                <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="DepartmentKey" />
                <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="MerchArea" />
                <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="Department" />

            </dxg:GridControl.Columns>            
        </dxg:GridControl>
```

The MemoEdit control and Combobox control inside the grid is not opening when clicked. Should I add any other tag to make the controls open when clicked on the cell?

Answer (score 0):

I added AllowEditing="True" property for the columns in which these controls are embedded in GridControl.